# Python set decimal precision

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writting a small code for encode with arithmetic encoding. I need to set a determinate precision but I must be doing something wrong. This is the code :

```
def encode(string, probabilities):
    getcontext().prec = 28
    start = 0.0
    width = 1.0
    for ch in string:
        d_start, d_width = probabilities[ch]
        start += d_start*width
        width *= d_width  
    return random.uniform(start, start + width)
```

As I've read in the python documentation getcontext().prec should set the precision I'm willing to work with. After some iterations, d_start and d_with is very small ( ~ e^-20 ) and the variables start and width stay with the same valor from that moment on.

If further information is needed please don't hesistate asking for it.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1: Proper indentation of the code

Edit 2: I've made a print of d_start after each sum to show what I mean by saying "and the variables start and width stay with the same valor from that moment on. "

Here you have the results:

```
0.0
0.16
0.224
0.224
0.22784
0.22784
0.2280448
0.22812672
0.22812672
0.2281316352
0.2281316352
0.228131897344
0.228132002202
0.228132002202
0.228132008493
0.228132008493
0.228132008829
0.228132008963
0.228132008963
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
0.228132008971
```

Comment: What is getcontext? Also, indent your code properly please

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the fast reply. Sorry for the stupid question I am about to ask but I've just started coding with python. What do you mean what is getcontext? I thought getcontext was the entire context of the program ( based on this https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html ). Probably I am wrong so please, make your point. Also, Identation is now correct!

Comment: All of your start and width variables need to be *Decimal* instances, for the precision to take effect.

Comment: @tknbr What is your input & desired output?

Comment: @guidot I think my variables start and width are, right now, floats, I'll try to convert them to deciaml and post the results.

Comment: @AniMenon my desired output will be the precision not to stop at certain decimal ( fixed ) instead I would like to set the precision I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `getcontext().prec` is only used for `decimal.Decimal` variables... and you define `start` and `width` as float.

You should force usage of Decimal, for example that way (assuming a `from decimal import *`)

```
def encode(string, probabilities):
    getcontext().prec = 28
    start = Decimal('0.0')
    width = Decimal('1.0')
    for ch in string:
        d_start, d_width = probabilities[ch]
        start += Decimal(d_start)*width
        width *= Decimal(d_width)
    return random.uniform(float(start), float(start + width))
```